# Nesting helper functions inside a function for readability purposes

Tags: javascript, optimization, refactoring, code-snippets

So I am currently reading through [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and I really like the idea of super small functions that each tell their own "story".  I also really like the way he puts how code should be written to be read in terms of "TO paragraphs", which I've decided to kind of rename in my head to "in order to"

Anyway I have been refactoring alot of code to include more meaningful names and to make the flow in which it will be read a little better and I have stumbled into something that I am unsure on and maybe some gurus here could give me some solid advice!

I know that code-styles is a highly controversial and subjective topic, but hopefully I wont get reamed out by this post.

Thanks everyone!

PSA: I am a noob, fresh out of College creating a web app using the MEAN stack  for an internal project in an internship at the moment.

Clean Code refactor

```
 //Modal Controller stuff above.  vm.task is an instance variable
vm.task = vm.data.task;
castTaskDataTypesForForm();

  function castTaskDataTypesForForm() {
    castPriorityToInt();
    castReminderInHoursToInt();
    castDueDateToDate();
    getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString();
  }

  function castPriorityToInt() {
    vm.task.priority = vm.task.priority === undefined ?
      0 : parseInt(vm.task.priority);
  }

  function castReminderInHoursToInt() {
    vm.task.reminderInHours = vm.task.reminderInHours === undefined ?
      0 : parseInt(vm.task.reminderInHours);
  }

  function castDueDateToDate() {
    vm.task.dueDate = new Date(vm.task.dueDate);
  }

  function getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString() {
    vm.task.assignee = getUserFromId(vm.task.assignee);
  }
```

Possibly better refactor? / My question ----------------------------

```
//Modal Controller stuff above.  vm.task is an instance variable
vm.task = vm.data.task;
castTaskDataTypesForForm();

  function castTaskDataTypesForForm() {
    castPriorityToInt();
    castReminderInHoursToInt();
    castDueDateToDate();
    getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString();

    function castPriorityToInt() {
      vm.task.priority = vm.task.priority === undefined ?
        0 : parseInt(vm.task.priority);
    }

    function castReminderInHoursToInt() {
      vm.task.reminderInHours = vm.task.reminderInHours === undefined ?
        0 : parseInt(vm.task.reminderInHours);
    }

    function castDueDateToDate() {
      vm.task.dueDate = new Date(vm.task.dueDate);
    }

    function getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString() {
      vm.task.assignee = getUserFromId(vm.task.assignee);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's arguably better to not define the helpers within the function, since they'll get recreated every time the main function gets called. Depending on your architecture, hide them in the same scope as in your first example. Or use a IIFE to create a closure around them so the helpers stay private. Or put them on the prototype of the module containing the main function (if it exists). Without knowing the structure of the rest of your code, I'd go for the IIFE.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for giving me something to look into!  Never heard of an IIFE, looking into them now to see what goodies they have for me.

Also because of the way that this is being used and the architecture of it this can and is only being called once.  So as far them being recreated it is a non issue.

Comment: @Shilly if you want, post this an an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the IIFE example here so I have more room to work with. I'm not saying this is the best option, it's the one I would use with the info the OP gave us.

```
var castTaskDataTypesForForm = (function() {
    var castPriorityToInt = function castPriorityToInt() { ... },
        castReminderInHoursToInt = function castReminderInHoursToInt() { .. },
        castDueDateToDate = function castDueDateToDate() { ... },
        getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString = function getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString() { ... };
    return function castTaskDataTypesForForm() {
        castPriorityToInt();
        castReminderInHoursToInt();
        castDueDateToDate();
        getAssigneObjFromAssigneeString();
    };
}());
vm.task = vm.data.task;
castTaskDataTypesForForm();
```

This way the helper functions only get defined once and are kept private inside the closure. You can obv remove the var x = function x syntax if you prefer the function x() style.

edit: If the function only gets called once, your own examples are probably the cleaner code. The reason you'd use the IIFE syntax would be to keep the helper functions only accesible by the main function, like in your own second example.

Comment: Very interesting, yeah I just read an article about it and it seems that another way to do it would be to literally just wrap it in parens.  Being in the god forsaken comment window I'm going to chop out alot of the fluff but


(function castTaskDataTypesForForm() { ... }());


This worked out rather nicely.  The way that you are doing it is more or less the same thing...right?

I do like how you explicitly call the function, does the function have to be defined before the call?

Comment: I'd rather not use function expressions for this. Use regular functions, they read better, is less prone to silly syntax errors yet is still scoped correctly.

Comment: @slebetman I agree, I am not a huge fan of function expressions as well.  Is what I am talking about in my comment on this what you are talking about? (function castTaskDataTypesForForm() { ... }());

Comment: @Michael: No. It's all the `var functions....,functions..;` inside the IIFE

Comment: The outer function expression is mechanics so is necessary and we have no choice. It's the inner expressions that are useless

Comment: @slebetman Ahhh this combined with Shilly's edit, it all came around.  I see what you are saying.  Thank you!

Comment: Hence I included that you don't have to use the expression style. It's just my personal preference, since declarations are just shorthand for the named expressions and I usually want to explicitly show they are variables as well.

Comment: One thing that I am not entirely clear on, with my original way where I declared the functions inside the main function castTaskDataTypesForForm() the main pitfall is that if it's called more than once all it's private (helper) functions will have to get re added to the stack, which is obviously not efficient.

So the main attraction for the IIFE, in this case is to have it so only castTaskDataTypesForForm is exposed, and have the private functions residing on the stack and not get re-declared?  Is this a misuse of an IIFE, the name sounds like it should be a one and done type of function.

Comment: Hmm, I think your usage of stack isn't the same as the current call stack in javascript. Do you mean the scope of the function? When calling the main function, the helper functions in scope of the main, will be added to the call stack and disappear once they are executed. But the scope of the function resides in the heap/memory I think. And yes, you use an IIFE to 'simulate' private methods only the main function can access. The IIFE is only run once (one and done) and then the outer variable has the function returned from within the IIFE. But the scope it runs with is saved in memory.

Comment: Interesting, I most definitely have to look more into this!  By stack I meant memory stack, I don't know the language well enough to really get into the details of what is fully going on it seems.  Lots to learn!  Thank you for taking your time out to explain these things @Shilly I appreciate it!  I'll take it from here and stop bothering you haha.  Enjoy the rest of your day/night.

Answer (score 1):

MEANjs uses the second method sometimes (with callbacks for example). I personally think it's nice if you are not intending to use those helpers outside of the main function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I think combined with @Shilly answer with taking into account if they will be recreated or not is exactly what I was looking for.